# IIS 7, MVC 3 and WebSite/WebApplication problem - Updated: 2011-04-21

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, iis-7, asp.net-mvc-routing

**Solved using this post:**
[Can you convert an ASP.NET MVC Application to a Web Site using ASP.NET MVC and what problems might you run into?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1029391/can-you-convert-an-asp-net-mvc-application-to-a-web-site-using-asp-net-mvc-and-wh)

**EDIT: 2011-apr-21 (Got rid of the previous code to make it easier to read, some responses and comments are from the old post)**

So i am trying to get my new MVC 3 page to work with IIS 7.

Here are the steps that i have taken so far:

IIS:

1) Create a new website in IIS 7 and set it to use .NET 4.0 (Integrated mode)

WebSite:

1) I just installed the new VS 2010 and MVC 3 (3 days ago), the MVC 3 i downloaded 3 days ago from asp.net/mvc.

2) I created a new MVC 3 project, File->New Project->Asp.Net MVC 3 Web Application.

Now i publish the project to a file path (like c:\project\newtestmvcapp

3) I upload the entire contents of the folder (newtestmvcapp) and poff it works.

I now remove the files from the domain.

4) I upload the normal files thats in the project path. I upload all folders except Bin, Obj and properties.

5) I run the page and now i get the following error: Could not load type 'MvcApplication1.MvcApplication'. <%@ Application CodeBehind="Global.asax.cs" Inherits="MvcApplication1.MvcApplication" Language="C#" %>

6) I change the CodeBehind to CodeFile and i get the following error: Missing partial modifier on declaration of type 'MvcApplication1.MvcApplication'; another partial declaration of this type exists. public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication

7) I change this: public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication , into this: public partial class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication

8) Now i just get an error that the resource (ex. Index can't be found or about or any other page) If i upload a test.htm it works, if i upload a forms page test.aspx it works. Just not the MVC.

**EDIT:** I found some article about the difference between a WebSite and a WebAppplication. Could that be the reason? If so, how can i change this MVC 3 project to be a website (thus allowing the project to be compiled at runtime). There isn't a File->New Web Site->MVC 3 Website in VS2010.

We want to be able to just upload a new view or a controller to the server and the server should then compile it for us. (Test/Dev server).

Comment: What is your .Net version in your Application Pool?

Comment: In IIS it says Framework: 4.0, Managed pipeline: Integrated, Identity: NetworkService

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This:

> In VS2010, i get the following red underlined "UrlRoutingModule" in add name="UrlRoutingModule" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule, System.Web.Routing, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"

Seems to point out you're using the `System.Web.Routing` dll of `.NET 3.5`.

Since you're building an `MVC 3` app, am I right in assuming you're using `.NET 4`? If so, this appears to indicate that you're referencing the wrong version of `System.Web.Routing`.

Was this by any chance an MVC 2 app that you converted to MVC 3?

---

**NOTE**

This answer is massively edited and has nothing to do with my original answer. I point this out because @Patrick's comment to my answer could be confusing.

Comment: I added Network Service with those attributes, but i still get a 404.

Comment: @Patrick - I've had 2nd thoughts on my answer and have updated it heavily.

Comment: Nope, i created a new MVC 3 project in VS 2010 and uploaded that project. I haven't created any controllers/views or anything to this. That routing routine i found at the following url:
http://community.aspnix.com/windows-manuals-tutorials-how-tos/2676-how-fix-http-error-404-when-running-mvc-iis7.html
I also should point out that i just installed the .NET 4 framework, VS 2010 and MVC 3. We are using VS 2008, .NET 3.5 and forms for our other web sites (different application pool in IIS).

Comment: Why not install mvc3 on the server so you have a solid starting point with necessary changes already implemented on the system? is it a hosted solution and you can't?

Comment: @Patrick - Is .NET 4 installed on the server? if it isn't, are you bin deploying `System.Web.Routing`? It would normally be in the GAC so VS will not be deploying it by default and you'd still have the conflicting version issue.

Comment: This is an old response to my old post (in which i wasn't clear enough about my intentions, i'm sorry for that)

Answer (score 1):

I just wrote a blogpost 'bout this issue, although it's more about integrating MVC3 in a existing WebSite Project the same rules apply. You should be able to convert your WebApplication to a Website by right clicking the project in VS, there should be an option to convert in the menu.
To get MVC3 running in a WebSite Project just put the Controllers and Models-folder under App_Code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Open command prompt as administrator and insert the following text:

If you are using a 32bit machine:
"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis.exe -i"

For 64bit machine:
"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis.exe -i"

If that doesn't work try this:

Right-click the System.Web.Routing reference, go to properties and set CopyLocal to true.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is an old response to my old post (in which i wasn't clear enough about my intentions, i'm sorry for that)